# Expectation of Joint Random Variables, Covariance

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, covariance

I'm trying to find the Covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

I see that the $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$.

I know how to find the expectation of single variables. I'm having troubles evaluation $E[XY]$. Can it be $X * E[Y]$?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
                          <kbd>Smoker</kbd> <kbd>Non-Smoker</kbd><kbd>Total</kbd>

<kbd>Heart Attack</kbd>      <kbd>0.03</kbd>      <kbd>0.03</kbd>              <kbd>0.06</kbd> 

<kbd>No Heart Attack</kbd><kbd>0.44</kbd>      <kbd>0.50</kbd>              <kbd>0.94</kbd> 
<kbd>Totals</kbd>                <kbd>0.47</kbd>      <kbd>0.53</kbd>

So the table contains all the joint distributions, and marginal distributions. I'm unsure how to plug into the discrete equation.
$\sum_x\sum_y x\, y\; \mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)$

I know that the $P(Smoker)=0.47$ and that $P(Heart Attack)=0.06$
and that $P(Smoker \cap Heart Attack) = 0.03$.

So this mean that $E[Smoker$ $HeartAttack] = 0.47 * 0.03 * 0.06$?

Also, is the $E[Smoker] = P(Smoker)$ *(aka is expectation equal to the marginal probability?)*

Comment: $XE(Y)$ is not a reasonable candidate, it is a random variable, not a number, To compute $E(XY)$ we will usually need to know the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Maybe that was given to you. For help in solving your problem, you will need to specify the full problem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I updated to include the full problem.

Comment: The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have not been defined, It may be that $X=1$ if the person is a smoker, $0$ otherwise, and $Y=1$ if person has heart attack, $0$ otherwise. Then $E(XY)=(1)(1)(0.03)$.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, $X\,\mathsf E(Y)$ is not a valid option.    As André Nicolas commented, that is a random variable while $\mathsf E(XY)$ is a constant.

What we *can* say is that: $\mathsf E(X\,Y) = \mathsf E\big(X\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\big)$

But we really do need to know what the joint distribution is to say more (or at least a marginal and conditional distribution).

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(XY) & = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} x\,y\;f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y & = \sum_x\sum_y x\, y\; \mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E\big((X\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\big) & = \underbrace{\int_{\Bbb R} x\,f_X(x) \int_{\Bbb R} y\; f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x }_\textsf{continuous valued random variables} & \underbrace{= \sum_x x\;\mathsf P(X=x)\,\sum_y y\;\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)
}_\textsf{discrete valued random variables}
\end{align}$$

And so forth.

Comment: I updated to include the full problem

Comment: @DarylBennett You need to define what the random variables actually measure.  What are their values for the given events?